# x86 assembly code basic

Tags: c, assembly, x86

What does the following code do...

```
   0x080489b0 <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x080489b1 <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x080489b3 <+3>: sub    $0x14,%esp
   0x080489b6 <+6>: push   %ebx
```

To my knowledge this sets up the stack in the first two lines, and then pushes the %esp down 14 essentially increasing the stack on the third line, and finally pushes a %ebx onto the stack (even though it's empty), which also increases the stack, and pushes %esp down one more spot.

Am I wrong on any of these steps? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are roughly correct.  The third instruction (sub $0x14,%esp) actually means to grow the stack by 0x14 = 20 bytes, perhaps for alignment reasons.  The fourth line means to push the 4-byte contents of %ebx onto the stack, subtracting 4 from %esp as a side effect.  The reason for this is that %ebx is a callee-save register: if a function modifies the contents of %ebx, it is expected to push %ebx onto the stack, then modify %ebx, then pop %ebx back off the stack so that the caller never notices a change in %ebx.  The other callee-save registers on x86 are %esi and %edi.

Comment: Okay, I realize I forgot that 0x14 is in hex, so it does grow the stack 20 bytes. I thought that the stack would be growing, but wasn't quite sure because I couldn't see how it would help anything, so back to reading it for me I guess :P thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. `sub $0x14, %esp` subtracts hexadecimal 0x14 (decimal 20) from the stack pointer, which is equivalent to the space used by 5 dwords.

Comment: Oh yeah I always forget to convert the hex into decimal :P so the stack would expand from this by 5 dwords. Thanks!

Comment: It could be setting up space for: 5 "local" dwords or a "local" variable to hold a 20 byte string.